# i want to get&set the value in excel .xls file and get the error message from application

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

i want to get the (valid and invalid) data from excel .xls file and apply that in my application login page.when the error message is display.i want to write failed in excel file.from my code, i can get the value from excel and apply it in my application but cant write the output in excel.i attached my code here.anyone please help me to fix this.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class exceltowrite {

public FileInputStream fis = null;
public FileOutputStream fos = null;
public HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
public HSSFSheet sheet = null;
public HSSFRow row = null;
public HSSFCell cell = null;
String xlFilePath;

public exceltowrite(String string, String xlFilePath) throws IOException {
    this.xlFilePath = xlFilePath;
    fis = new FileInputStream(xlFilePath);
    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    fis.close();
}

public static void main(String[]args) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException, InterruptedException  {
    for(int i=1;i<=29;i++) {
        String u1 =exceltowrite.getdata(i,0);
        String p1=exceltowrite.getdata(i,1);
        WebDriver d1=new FirefoxDriver();
        d1.get("http:\\www.google.com");
        d1.get("napplication site");
        d1.findElement(By.name("AdminLoginForm[email]")).sendKeys(u1);
        d1.findElement(By.name("AdminLoginForm[password]")).sendKeys(p1);
        d1.findElement(By.name("login-button")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);     
        WebElement e1= d1.findElement(By.xpath("email error message path"));
        String s1=e1.getText();
        WebElement e2=d1.findElement(By.xpath("password error message path"));
        String s2=e2.getText();        
        if(s1.equals("Email cannot be blank.")) {
            System.out.println("emailid failed");
        d1.quit();           
            if(s2.equals("Password cannot be blank.")) {
                System.out.println("password failed");
                d1.quit();
            } else {
                System.out.println("password pass");
                d1.quit();
              }
            } else {
                d1.quit();
              }
        }   
   }

public static String getdata(int i, int j) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException {

    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("file path");
    Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
    String s=wb.getSheet("Sheet1").getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
    return s;
}

 public boolean setCellData(String sheetName, int colNumber, int rowNum, String value)
    {
        try
        {
            sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
           row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
 System.out.println(row);
            cell = row.getCell(colNumber);            
 System.out.println(cell);
            cell.setCellValue(value);
            fos = new FileOutputStream(xlFilePath);
            workbook.write(fos);
            fos.close();
            System.out.println("Finished");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return  false;
        }
        return true;
    }}
 }
```

my another class is this

```
public class Demo {

 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
// exceltowrite at=new  exceltowrite("file path");
        for(int j=0;j<=29;j++){
            at.setCellData("Sheet1",2,j,"failed");
 }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void write() throws IOException {
    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    String downlpad = home + "\\Downloads";
    File file = new File(downlpad + "\\" + "Suhit-File-to-Download.xlsx");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Java Books");
    ArrayList<Object> bookData = new ArrayList<>();
    bookData.add("Name");
    bookData.add("Address");
    bookData.add("Number");

    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < bookData.size(); i++) {
        XSSFCell cell3 = row.createCell(i);
        cell3.setCellValue((String) bookData.get(i));
    }
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    workbook.close();
```

}

Comment: thanks for your response suhit..how can i util this code with application code?